# Generate rows from string of numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, data-extraction, oracle18c

by I have an Oracle 18c table that has strings like this:

```
select
    '((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))' as multipart_lines
    --There are more rows in the actual table.
from
    dual

    MULTIPART_LINES                                              
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    ((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))
--      v1      v2           v3           v4           v5
--  |            part 1             | |          part 2         |
```

- Individual coordinates are separated by spaces.
- Vertices (X Y Z coordinates) are separated by commas.
- Line parts are wrapped in brackets and separated by commas.

---

In a query, I want to generate rows for each vertex:

```
PART_NUM   VERTEX_NUM          X          Y          Z
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          0          5          0
         1          2         10         10      11.18
         1          3         30          0      33.54
         2          1         50         10      33.54
         2          2         60         10      43.54
```

- I want to do this in a query. I don't want to insert rows into a table.
- Unfortunately, I don't have CREATE TYPE privileges in the database. But I *can* create functions (and of course, inline functions are an option too).

---

How can I generate rows from the numbers (vertices) in the string?

Related: [Oracle Ideas - generate_series() function](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4497973/generate-series-function)

Comment: Its unclear how you are deriving the part_num, vertex_numfrom the data you provided

Comment: @Pugzly Individual coordinates are separated by spaces.
Vertices (X Y Z coordinates) are separated commas.
Line parts are wrapped in brackets and separated by commas. I updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative - here is how you can process the input strings to convert them to proper JSON strings; then the task becomes trivial. Showing just the JSON-ization first, separately, as it really is the meaningful part of this solution; then after I show the query and result, I will complete the solution by adding the JSON manipulation.

```
with
  inputs (id, multipart_lines) as (
    select 2810,
      '((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))'
                                  from dual union all
    select 7284, '((-2.3 0.2 3))' from dual
  )
, j (id, ml) as (
    select id,
           regexp_replace(
             regexp_replace(
               regexp_replace(
                 regexp_replace(
                   regexp_replace(multipart_lines
                   , '\(\s*\(\s*', '[[[')
                 , '\s*\)\s*\)', ']]]')
               , '\s*\)\s*,\s*\(\s*', '],[')
             , '\s*,\s*', '],[')
           , '\s+', ',')
    from   inputs
  )
select * from j;



   ID ML                                                                  
----- --------------------------------------------------------------------
 2810 [[[0,5,0],[10,10,11.18],[30,0,33.54]],[[50,10,33.54],[60,10,43.54]]]
 7284 [[[-2.3,0.2,3]]]
```

Your inputs should really look like the strings in column `ml` in my subquery `j` - then you could process them like this:

```
with
  inputs (id, multipart_lines) as (
            ........
  )
, j (id, ml) as (
            ........
  )
select id, part_num, vertex_num, x, y, z
from   j,
       json_table(ml, '$[*]'
                  columns (
                    part_num for ordinality,
                    nested path '$[*]'
                    columns (
                      vertex_num for ordinality,
                      x number path '$[0]',
                      y number path '$[1]',
                      z number path '$[2]'
                    )
                  )
       )
order by id, part_num, vertex_num   --  if needed
;
```

The output is the same as in my other answer.

Comment: Excellent : Thank you - I'm struggling to get to grips with json and arrays and functions which process or use tables. Can you advise any helpful sources? - for Oracle or Postrgres ou MSSQL

Comment: @Kendle - Unlike most of the Oracle documentation, the JSON part is actually quite readable. In addition, one site I (and apparently many!) like for learning all things Oracle is oracle-base.com. For example, to read about lateral joins (which apply in particular to selecting from JSON strings or XML strings in a table), you would do a google search for something like `lateral site:oracle-base.com` (note how you can specify the web site to search - if you didn't know that already).

Comment: Thanks mathguy. I'll look that up.

Comment: mathguy : You might find @SolomonYakobson's answer interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063021/5576771

Comment: @User1974 - Solomon's first answer is the same as my regexp-based answer (just arranged slightly differently). As to macros - I did not install Oracle 19 or higher yet (I don't work in the field, I just play with Oracle for my own learning), I am still using 12.2, so I would not have come up with that. In any case, I would rather use the JSON based answer; if the format of your inputs will change in the future, you will have to adapt the first step (generating proper JSON from the input), but you won't need to touch anything in the second part of the query.

Comment: You do not need regular expressions and can use `REPLACE` and `TRANSLATE` instead [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=18728ae9959c08d18b645e9751448abf)

Answer (score 3):

It would be so much simpler if the input was in some standard format - for example JSON. Then the task would be trivial. Do you have any power over that?

If not, you could either transform the input into proper JSON (or similar), or you could attack the problem directly. I illustrate the latter below, assuming Oracle version 12.1 or higher.

```
with
  inputs (id, multipart_lines) as (
    select 2810,
      '((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))'
                                  from dual union all
    select 7284, '((-2.3 0.2 3))' from dual
  )
select id, part_num, vertex_num, x, y, z
from   inputs 
       cross join lateral
       ( select  level as part_num,
                 regexp_substr(multipart_lines,
                               '\(([^()]+)\)', 1, level, null, 1) as part
         from    dual
         connect by level <= regexp_count(multipart_lines, '\(') - 1
       )
       cross join lateral
       (
         select  level as vertex_num,
                 regexp_substr(part, '[^,]+', 1, level) as vertex
         from    dual
         connect by level <= regexp_count(part, ',') + 1
       )
       cross join lateral
       (
         select   to_number(regexp_substr(vertex, '[^ ]+', 1, 1)) as x,
                  to_number(regexp_substr(vertex, '[^ ]+', 1, 2)) as y,
                  to_number(regexp_substr(vertex, '[^ ]+', 1, 3)) as z
         from     dual
       )
order by id, part_num, vertex_num   --  if needed
;
```

Output (from the sample inputs I included in the query):

```
        ID   PART_NUM VERTEX_NUM          X          Y          Z
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      2810          1          1          0          5          0
      2810          1          2         10         10      11.18
      2810          1          3         30          0      33.54
      2810          2          1         50         10      33.54
      2810          2          2         60         10      43.54
      7284          1          1       -2.3         .2          3
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't have a way to output the data to JSON, XML, etc. I've submitted a *request for enhancement* to the software vendor. But I doubt they'll ever do it.

Comment: @User1974 - With that in mind, I just posted an answer showing how you can transform your inputs from the current format (as provided to you from the outside world) to JSON format before using JSON functions. One or the other may prove faster on your data; I would personally choose the JSON approach, unless it proves to be too slow, just because it seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

I see that mathguy has got there. I was working with `from json_table` but I can't unnest 2 rows at a time otherwise I'd be basically there with a second use of row_number() over (partition by Paru_num).

> ```
> create table sample(value varchar(100));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into sample values 
> ('((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))')
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> with a as (
> select '["'|| regexp_replace(value,'\(|\)','') ||'"]' a from sample
> ),
> b as (
> select regexp_replace(a,', ?','","') b from a
> ),
> c as (
> SELECT value c
> FROM json_table( (select b from b) , '$[*]'
>                 COLUMNS (value PATH '$')
>                )
> ),
> d as (
> SELECT
>   c d,
>   instr(c,' ') s1,
>   instr(c,' ',instr(c,' ')+1) s2
> from c)
> select 
>  substr(d,0,s1) x,
>  substr(d,s1+1,s2-s1) y,
>  substr(d,s2+1) z
> from d
> ```

> ```
> X   | Y   | Z    
> :-- | :-- | :----
> 0   | 5   | 0    
> 10  | 10  | 11.18
> 30  | 0   | 33.54
> 50  | 10  | 33.54
> 60  | 10  | 43.54
> ```

> ```
> with a as (
> select '["'|| regexp_replace(value,'\(+|\)+','"') ||'"]' a from sample
> ),
> b as(
> select replace(a,'""','"')b from a
> ),
> c as (
> SELECT 
>   row_number() over (order by 'zero') pn,
>   value c
> FROM json_table( (select b from b) , '$[*]'
>                 COLUMNS (value PATH '$')
> )    ),
> d as (
> select '["'|| pn ||' '|| regexp_replace(c,', ?','","'||pn||' ')||'"]' d from c
> )
> select * from d
> ```
>
> ```
> | D                                          |
> | :----------------------------------------- |
> | ["1 0 5 0","1 10 10 11.18","1 30 0 33.54"] |
> | ["2 50 10 33.54","2 60 10 43.54"]          |
> ```

> ```
> with a as (
> select '["'|| regexp_replace(value,'\(+|\)+','"') ||'"]' a from sample
> ),
> b as(
> select replace(a,'""','"')b from a
> ),
> c as (
> SELECT 
>   row_number() over (order by 'zero') pn,
>   value c
> FROM json_table( (select b from b) , '$[*]'
>                 COLUMNS (value PATH '$')
> )    ),
> d as (
> select '["'|| pn ||' '|| regexp_replace(c,', ?','","'||pn||' ')||'"]' d from c
> ),
> e as (
> SELECT 
>   row_number() over (order by 'zero') pn,
>   value c
> FROM json_table( (select d from d) , '$[*]'
>                 COLUMNS (value PATH '$')
> )    )
> select * from e
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2795fb1c2a806b5166bba38bf5fa9313)*

Comment: lol - I started with JSON first too, and I was going the same way you started. After I posted the regexp answer I returned to JSON; I realized that there should be no strings anywhere. A single vertex must also be an array (nested at the third level) - see the second answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with only simple string functions (which are much faster than regular expressions) and recursive sub-queries:

```sql
WITH line_bounds (id, multipart_lines, line_no, spos, epos) AS (
    SELECT id,
           multipart_lines,
           1,
           2,
           INSTR(multipart_lines, ')', 2)
    FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
    SELECT id,
           multipart_lines,
           line_no + 1,
           epos + 2,
           INSTR(multipart_lines, ')', epos + 2)
    FROM   line_bounds
    WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET line_order,
row_bounds (id, line, line_no, row_no, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         SUBSTR(multipart_lines, spos + 1, epos - spos - 1),
         line_no,
         1,
         1,
         INSTR(
           SUBSTR(multipart_lines, spos + 1, epos - spos - 1),
           ',',
           1
         )
  FROM   line_bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         line,
         line_no,
         row_no + 1,
         epos + 2,
         INSTR(line, ',', epos + 2)
  FROM   row_bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id, line_no SET row_order,
column_bounds (id, line, line_no, row_no, xpos, ypos, zpos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         line,
         line_no,
         row_no,
         spos,
         INSTR(line, ' ', spos, 1),
         INSTR(line, ' ', spos, 2),
         epos
  FROM   row_bounds
)
SELECT id,
       line_no,
       row_no,
       SUBSTR(line, xpos + 0, ypos - xpos) AS x,
       SUBSTR(line, ypos + 1, zpos - ypos - 1) AS y,
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(line, zpos + 1)
       ELSE SUBSTR(line, zpos + 1, epos - zpos - 1)
       END AS z
FROM   column_bounds
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, multipart_lines) AS
  SELECT 1, '((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '((0 1 0, 0 2 0, 0 3 0),(0 4 0, 0 5 0))' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | LINE_NO | ROW_NO | X | Y | Z |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
> | 1 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 10 | 11.18 |
> | 1 | 1 | 3 | 30 | 0 | 33.54 |
> | 1 | 2 | 1 | 50 | 10 | 33.54 |
> | 1 | 2 | 2 | 60 | 10 | 43.54 |
> | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
> | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
> | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=34183ca15d32d32a7b35f3294fb54506)*

Answer (score 1):

Use `SDO_GEOMETRY` to parse the string and then use `SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT` to get each element and then `SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES` to get the vertices:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       e.elem_no,
       v.id AS coord_id,
       x,
       y,
       z
FROM   ( SELECT id,
                SDO_GEOMETRY('MULTILINESTRING '||multipart_lines) AS shape
         FROM   table_name
       ) t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL AS elem_no,
                SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT(t.shape, LEVEL) AS elem
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= SDO_UTIL.GETNUMELEM(t.shape)
       ) e
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(e.elem)) v
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, multipart_lines) AS
  SELECT 1, '((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '((0 1 0, 0 2 0, 0 3 0),(0 4 0, 0 5 0))' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | ELEM_NO | COORD_ID | X | Y | Z |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
> | 1 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 10 | 11.18 |
> | 1 | 1 | 3 | 30 | 0 | 33.54 |
> | 1 | 2 | 1 | 50 | 10 | 33.54 |
> | 1 | 2 | 2 | 60 | 10 | 43.54 |
> | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
> | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
> | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=afd003ecd9c527a2ab3ab56a868f3c28)*

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind me asking: Does your SQL client output a table in the Stack Overflow table markup format, or do you find you need to manually edit the output (from SQL+, etc) so that it shows up as a proper table like that?

Comment: @User1974 db<>fiddle generates it when you click on the "markdown" link (although at this moment it seems to be broken in Firefox but works in Chrome). I copy the lines between the `> <pre>` and `> </pre>` lines then add `|` characters before the first column but the markdown is 95+% generated for me.

Answer (score 0):

@SolomonYakobson provided this answer in an [Oracle Community post](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16834156/#Comment_16834156).

```
with sample as (
                select '((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))' as multipart_lines
                        --There are more rows in the actual table.
                  from  dual
               )
select  part_num,
        vertex_num,
        to_number(regexp_substr(vertex,'[^ ]+')) x,
        to_number(regexp_substr(vertex,'[^ ]+',1,2)) y,
        to_number(regexp_substr(vertex,'[^ ]+',1,3)) z
  from  sample,
        lateral(
                select  level part_num,
                        regexp_substr(multipart_lines,'\(([^()]+)',1,level,null,1) part
                  from  dual
                  connect by level < regexp_count(multipart_lines,'\(')
               ),
        lateral(
                select  level vertex_num,
                        regexp_substr(part,'[^,]+',1,level) vertex
                  from  dual
                  connect by level <= regexp_count(part,',') + 1
               )
/

  PART_NUM VERTEX_NUM          X          Y          Z
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          0          5          0
         1          2         10         10      11.18
         1          3         30          0      33.54
         2          1         50         10      33.54
         2          2         60         10      43.54
```

---

As well as an Oracle 19c solution:

```
create or replace
  function split_multipart_line(
                                p_line varchar2
                               )
    return varchar2
    sql_macro
    is
    begin
        return q'[
select  part_num,
        vertex_num,
        to_number(regexp_substr(vertex,'[^ ]+')) x,
        to_number(regexp_substr(vertex,'[^ ]+',1,2)) y,
        to_number(regexp_substr(vertex,'[^ ]+',1,3)) z
  from  dual,
        lateral(
                select  level part_num,
                        regexp_substr(p_line,'\(([^()]+)',1,level,null,1) part
                  from  dual
                  connect by level < regexp_count(p_line,'\(')
               ),
        lateral(
                select  level vertex_num,
                        regexp_substr(part,'[^,]+',1,level) vertex
                  from  dual
                  connect by level <= regexp_count(part,',') + 1
               )]';
end;
/

Function created.

SQL> with sample as (
  2                  select '((0 5 0, 10 10 11.18, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 43.54))' multipart_lines from dual union all
  3                  select '((1 2 3, 4 5 6, 7 8 9, 10 11 12),(22 33 44, 55 66 77))' multipart_lines from dual
  4                 )
  5  select  l.*
  6    from  sample,
  7          lateral(
  8                  select  *
  9                    from  split_multipart_line(multipart_lines)
 10                 ) l
 11  /


  PART_NUM VERTEX_NUM          X          Y          Z
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          0          5          0
         1          2         10         10      11.18
         1          3         30          0      33.54
         2          1         50         10      33.54
         2          2         60         10      43.54
         1          1          1          2          3
         1          2          4          5          6
         1          3          7          8          9
         1          4         10         11         12
         2          1         22         33         44
         2          2         55         66         77


11 rows selected.

SQL>
```