# Generate rows from JSON (SDO_GEOMETRY)

Tags: sql, json, oracle, parsing, oracle-spatial

I have a multi-part SDO_GEOMETRY that I can represent as **JSON** (Oracle 21c):

```
select
    json_object(* PRETTY) as  pretty_json
from
   (
    select
        '001' as line_id,
        sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING ((0.0 5.0, 10.0 10.0, 30.0 0.0), (50.0 10.0, 60.0 10.0))') as sdo_geom
    from
        dual
    )

PRETTY_JSON
--------------------------
{
  "LINE_ID" : "001",
  "SDO_GEOM" :
  {
    "SDO_GTYPE" : 2006,
    "SDO_SRID" : null,
    "SDO_POINT" :
    {
    },
    "SDO_ELEM_INFO" :
    [
      1,
      2,
      1,
      7,
      2,
      1
    ],
    "SDO_ORDINATES" :
    [
      0,
      5,
      10,
      10,
      30,
      0,
      50,
      10,
      60,
      10
    ]
  }
}
```

---

As an experiment, I want to find a way to **generate rows** from the JSON:

```
   LINE_ID   PART_NUM VERTEX_NUM          X          Y 
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
       001          1          1          0          5 
       001          1          2         10         10 
       001          1          3         30          0 
       001          2          1         50         10 
       001          2          2         60         10
```

Each row is a vertex of the geometry.

**Question:**

In an SQL query, is there a way to generate rows for each of the JSON vertices?

---

*I'm aware that SDO_GEOMETRY has a [GetVertices()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-9CF1E8A9-EBCB-4938-BBB6-C2AAFE4897A7) function that can be used for this -- it avoids the JSON step. That works, but in my case, I want to experiment with parsing vertices out of JSON text using SQL. If I find something that works, I want to use that same JSON extraction technique on a [user-defined datatype](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm) that doesn't have a GetVertices function.*

Comment: So, you are assuming you are given a JSON string, and you want to extract part number, vertex number, and coordinates from it. Obviously that doesn't make sense for **all** JSON strings; so you must be willing to accept some limitations on the input. Are you assuming that the JSON has exactly that structure (attributes with those specific names, etc.)? Then: for the question to make sense, the SDO_GTYPE must be exactly 2006 (assuming two-dimensional - or do you want it more general, allowing type 3006 for example?) [continued]

Comment: Do you also assume the SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY looks exactly like `(1,2,1[,n2,2,1[...]])`? Otherwise the geometry is not a multiline to begin with.

Comment: As an aside: I counted five questions you asked about this general problem here on SO in the past couple of weeks, plus several more on Oracle-tech. None of them shows an accepted answer. So - either you aren't getting any good answers, so we must then wonder why you keep coming back, copying the answer you get from one site to the other site and asking something new each time, or else you ARE getting good answers, but then why don't the various threads reflect that? People (me included) will stop working with you at some point, if we don't get a good explanation for that.

Comment: @mathguy Fair points, and I'll answer your other questions about the above post shortly. Yes, I can do better when it comes to accepting answers sooner. I'll spend some time on that this afternoon. I'd explain my work style like this: I'm in the middle of a very deep dive when it comes to learning about vertices, SDO_GEOMETRY, ST_GEOMETRY, and limitations & techniques with those spatial types. I'm trying to solve a number of different problems that I've been chipping away at for 5+ years. I'm finally making some headway, now that my skills have improved. [continued]

Comment: ...And so I have lots of different questions and ideas. But yes, they do come off as similar, which can be annoying. And I almost always get great answers. Thanks very much. Sometimes, people give a good answer, but it's not exactly what I had asked for (example, I ask about a custom aggregate function, but something different is provided). Other times, I'm obsessing over the answers, thinking about them for several days or weeks. I usually do accept an answer eventually and I think my long-term track record is good there. [continued]

Comment: ...When it comes to linking to answers between SO and Oracle-tech, I put forth an earnest effort to curate my posts by linking to related pages, so that anyone else with the same/similar problem can hopefully get the information they need. And sometimes answers find the cross posts interesting too. But I understand that it can seem excessive at times. … Long story short, I'm working like a madman to solve several similar long-standing problems, and have lots of questions as I go. But I hear what you’re saying. I'll try to find a way to be less annoying about it.

Comment: @mathguy Regarding your original questions about the post: I think your assumptions are accurate: *Assume the JSON has exactly that structure (attributes with those specific names). The SDO_GTYPE must be exactly 2006. Also, assume the SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY looks exactly like (1,2,1[,n2,2,1[...]]).* I'm starting to realize that this is more complicated than I originally thought. I had assumed that extracting values from JSON would be easy. But in this specific case, it seems not.

Comment: The problem is complicated because SDO_GEOMETRY is designed to encode many different types of geometries within a single set of structures. If you always work ONLY with multi-lines, it would be easier if you would develop your own mini-"sdo_geometry"; the JSON encoding should look like the nested arrays I produced in one of my answers to you on SO, or perhaps more structured with keys for part_no (value: array of parts, each being an array - or possibly a JSON object - for vertices). Then you can write your own methods for encoding, decoding, and analyzing such multi-lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method (adapted from [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076942/1509264) for 3D lines) is to use `SDO_GEOMETRY` and not to use JSON functions:

```sql
SELECT t.line_id,
       e.elem_no,
       v.id AS coord_id,
       x,
       y
FROM   ( SELECT '001' AS line_id,
                SDO_GEOMETRY(
                  'MULTILINESTRING ((0.0 5.0, 10.0 10.0, 30.0 0.0), (50.0 10.0, 60.0 10.0))'
                ) AS shape
         FROM   DUAL
       ) t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL AS elem_no,
                SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT(t.shape, LEVEL) AS elem
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= SDO_UTIL.GETNUMELEM(t.shape)
       ) e
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(e.elem)) v
```

But, if you assume that you are only working with 2D multi-lines (`GTYPE = 2006`) then you can get the output with JSON but its not simple:

```sql
WITH elements (line_id, elem_no, starting_offset, next_offset, ordinates) AS (
  SELECT '001' as line_id,
         elem_no,
         starting_offset,
         next_offset,
         ordinates
  FROM   JSON_TABLE(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             SDO_GEOMETRY(
               'MULTILINESTRING ((0.0 5.0, 10.0 10.0, 30.0 0.0), (50.0 10.0, 60.0 10.0))'
             )
           ),
           '$?(@.SDO_GTYPE==2006)'
           COLUMNS (
             ordinates       VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.SDO_ORDINATES',
             NESTED PATH '$.SDO_ELEM_INFO[*]' COLUMNS (
               item_no FOR ORDINALITY,
               item    NUMBER PATH '$'
             )
           )
         )
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    ORDER BY item_no
    MEASURES
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS elem_no,
      FIRST(starting_offset.item) AS starting_offset,
      FIRST(etype.item)           AS etype,
      FIRST(interpretation.item)  AS interpretation,
      NEXT(item)                  AS next_offset,
      FIRST(ordinates)            AS ordinates
    PATTERN (starting_offset etype interpretation)
    DEFINE starting_offset AS 1 = 1
  ) m
  WHERE (etype, interpretation) IN ((2, 1))
)
SELECT m.*
FROM   elements e
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT *
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  e.ordinates,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    coord_no FOR ORDINALITY,
                    coord    NUMBER PATH '$'
                  )
                )
         WHERE  coord_no >= e.starting_offset
         AND    (e.next_offset IS NULL OR coord_no < e.next_offset)
       )
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY line_id, elem_no
  ORDER BY coord_no
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS coord_id,
    FIRST(x.coord) AS X,
    FIRST(y.coord) AS Y
  PATTERN (X Y)
  DEFINE X AS 1 = 1
) m
```

Which both output:

> | LINE_ID | ELEM_NO | COORD_ID | X | Y |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 001 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
> | 001 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 10 |
> | 001 | 1 | 3 | 30 | 0 |
> | 001 | 2 | 1 | 50 | 10 |
> | 001 | 2 | 2 | 60 | 10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1299724f8645a844796d6db54df597df)*