# Multi-part geometries: Get line & part number when extracting parts (via SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT_ALL)

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry, oracle-spatial, object-type

I have multi-part SDO_GEOMETRIES in Oracle 18c.

I can extract the *parts* as individual rows using the [SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT_ALL()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-0194302C-B293-4C1D-99AB-A1B3CC60EE47) function:

> ```
> with cte as (
> --Each part is wrapped in brackets and separated by commas: (p1),(p2)
> select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((1 1 1, 2 2 2),(3 3 3, 4 4 4))')    as shape from dual union all --3D: (X,Y,Z)
> select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((5 5, 6 6),(7 7, 8 8),(9 9, 0 0))') as shape from dual union all --2D: (X,Y)
> select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((1 1, 2 2))')                       as shape from dual           --2D: (X,Y)
>     )
> select
>     a.object_value,
>     sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(a.object_value)
> from
>     cte,
>     table(sdo_util.extract_all(shape)) a
>
> OBJECT_VALUE         SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(A.OBJECT_VALUE)                                         
> -------------------- ---------------------------------------
> [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (1.0 1.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0 2.0)                                           
> [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (3.0 3.0 3.0, 4.0 4.0 4.0)                                           
> [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (5.0 5.0, 6.0 6.0)                                                   
> [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (7.0 7.0, 8.0 8.0)                                                   
> [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (9.0 9.0, 0.0 0.0)                                                   
> [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (1.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6b73e6b0ad34fc1f982ee6731fb36837)*

---

I want to add the following columns to the query:

- MULTILINE_NUM (the original multi-part line number)
- PART_NUM

> ```
> MULTILINE_NUM PART_NUM OBJECT_VALUE         SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(A.OBJECT_VALUE)                               
>
> ------------- -------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------
>             1        1 [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (1.0 1.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0 2.0)                                           
>             1        2 [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (3.0 3.0 3.0, 4.0 4.0 4.0)                                           
>             2        1 [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (5.0 5.0, 6.0 6.0)                                                   
>             2        2 [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (7.0 7.0, 8.0 8.0)                                                   
>             2        3 [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (9.0 9.0, 0.0 0.0)                                                   
>             3        1 [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY] LINESTRING (1.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0)
> ```

When adding those columns, I don't want to "fake it" after-the-fact using window functions, etc.

I want to extract that information directly from the geometries, to ensure the numbers are correct (i.e., part number shouldn't be arbitrary; it should reflect the part number order from the original geometry).

---

Is there a way to get the MULTILINE_NUM and PART_NUM from the `table(sdo_util.extract_all(shape))` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076942/1509264), you can use:

```sql
with cte (shape) as (
  --Each part is wrapped in brackets and separated by commas: (p1),(p2)
  select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((1 1 1, 2 2 2),(3 3 3, 4 4 4))')    from dual union all --3D: (X,Y,Z)
  select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((5 5, 6 6),(7 7, 8 8),(9 9, 0 0))') from dual union all --2D: (X,Y)
  select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((1 1, 2 2))')                       from dual           --2D: (X,Y)
)
select c.multiline_num,
       e.part_no,
       sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(e.elem)
from   ( SELECT ROWNUM AS multiline_num,
                shape
         FROM   cte
       ) c
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL AS part_no,
                SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT(c.shape, LEVEL) AS elem
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= SDO_UTIL.GETNUMELEM(c.shape)
       ) e;
```

Which outputs:

> | MULTILINE_NUM | PART_NO | SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(E.ELEM) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | LINESTRING (1.0 1.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0 2.0) |
> | 1 | 2 | LINESTRING (3.0 3.0 3.0, 4.0 4.0 4.0) |
> | 2 | 1 | LINESTRING (5.0 5.0, 6.0 6.0) |
> | 2 | 2 | LINESTRING (7.0 7.0, 8.0 8.0) |
> | 2 | 3 | LINESTRING (9.0 9.0, 0.0 0.0) |
> | 3 | 1 | LINESTRING (1.0 1.0, 2.0 2.0) |

---

Or, using `SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT_ALL`:

```sql
with cte (shape) as (
  --Each part is wrapped in brackets and separated by commas: (p1),(p2)
  select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((1 1 1, 2 2 2),(3 3 3, 4 4 4))')    from dual union all --3D: (X,Y,Z)
  select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((5 5, 6 6),(7 7, 8 8),(9 9, 0 0))') from dual union all --2D: (X,Y)
  select sdo_geometry('MULTILINESTRING((1 1, 2 2))')                       from dual           --2D: (X,Y)
)
select c.multiline_num,
       e.part_no,
       sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(e.elem)
from   ( SELECT ROWNUM AS multiline_num,
                shape
         FROM   cte
       ) c
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT ROWNUM AS part_no,
                a.object_value AS elem
         FROM   TABLE(SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT_ALL(c.shape)) a
       ) e;
```

Which outputs the same.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2ef126e5702826359636f6d25cfb78ff)*